# Generate numbers where Each pair of adjacent digits also occurs in the original number

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I would like to output all similar numbers of a number, where:

1. Each pair of adjacent digits also occurs in the original number.
2. The new numbers has the same number of digits as the original
3. The order in which the numbers are generated doesn't matter

For example suppose I'm given a number 12314, then I have the pairs 12,23,31,14

I should generate `[12314,31231,12312,23123]`.

If I'm given numbers like 52 or 11111 then I should get only 52/11111 respectively.

I have already written code that generates the pairs `[12,23,31,14]`, and generate all possible permutations of this list of pairs. However, the permutations produce numbers that are longer than the original, and many of these permutations are invalid. For example, when `1214` appears in the permutation, the permutation is not valid since "21" is not in the original number.

I'd like to know how to proceed. It looks very inefficient to filter out the invalid ones from all permutations.

Comment: Show your code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to generate the required numbers.

The idea is to maintain only valid numbers at any stage and to display when the original length and length of your number are equal.

```
// pairs[i][j] is true if j is immediately after i in the original number
bool pairs[10][10];

// curr_num is a valid number according to the constraint given
// curr_len is the number of digits in curr_num
// length is the number of digits in the number given
void generate(int curr_num, int curr_len, int length){
    if(cur_len == length){
         display curr_num;
     } else {
        // extract last digit & check what digits can follow that
        int last = curr_num % 10;
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++)
            if(pairs[last][i])
                generate(curr_num * 10 + i , curr_len + 1, length); 
    }
}

for(digit in original_number)
    generate(digit, 1, length);
```

You could optimize the code by making *pairs* an adjacency list than an adjacency matrix.